# Migrate wordpress database to postgres

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, postgresql

I am looking to migrate my wordpress database to a rails application with postgresql. How can I migrate the encrypted password of my users, so that they don't have to recreate a new password?

Comment: Password is md5 hash with salt

Answer (score 0):

Migrating passwords can be done in the same way as for the other string columns, since password is a string stored in encrypted format the same can be moved as a string to the postgresql.